# 'declare' modifier cannot appear on a class element,unable to create build in angular8

Tags: angular, angular8, filestack

getting this error **ERROR in src/app/uploadpix/uploadpix.component.ts(17,3): error TS1031: 'declare' modifier cannot appear on a class element.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJoDB.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your intent to use `declare` here? If you only wish to declare a member variable, you could just say `FilestackTransform: any` without the `declare` keyword. It is considered declared as a member variable of the class.

Comment: hello michael, I am using Filestack Transformation UI, without declaring FilestackTransform is getting error showing cannot found name, so i declared the method ( please see screen shot http://prntscr.com/rf78i6)

Comment: In that case, unfortunately I don't see where the issue is.